# How to go to a page, load, go to a page, load, etc

Tags: c#, automation

I want to be able to automate this so I can go to one page, load, do code, next page, load, do code. Right now I'm using timers but that doesn't seem as efficient as waiting for the page to load. Here's what I thought would work but it just goes to the last site and then loads.

My approach is probably wrong so I was hoping maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url1 = "http://google.com";
    string url2 = "http://yahoo.com";
    string url3 = "http://msn.com";

    webBrowser1.Navigate(url1);
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url2);
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url3);
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to wait for the first page to complete before starting the next page, you should chain the navigations sequentially by waiting until the `DocumentCompleted` event fires for the previous URL:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += OnGoogleCompleted;

    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
}

private void OnGoogleCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= OnGoogleCompleted;
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += OnYahooCompleted;

    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://yahoo.com");
}

private void OnYahooCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= OnYahooCompleted;
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += OnMsnCompleted;

    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://msn.com");
}

private void OnMsnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How will this scale? Say there are 5 or 10 or 20 urls.

Comment: @bic: It is single-threaded, so the more URLs, the more time it will take. That is how the OP specified it, though, so I have to assume it is correct for the scenario.

Comment: @Bryan Watts: Sure I get that its a solution to the OP, but I think helping the OP to understand the problem and how to resolve issues like this is more important. What I meant by scaling was that for each new url more code has to be written specifically for that url. In other words if the OP had say 20 urls would you have arrived at the solution above? Anyhow, just my 2c

Comment: @bic: Ah, you meant scaling at development time, not at runtime. That is a fair distinction; nXu raised the same concern with his answer. If there are truly three known URLs, I think the explicit handlers more clearly express the dependencies between pages loads. That approach does not have the complexity of a generalized single-handler solution. If the problem is more complex than the question states, I would be in favor of a more complex solution.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need different event handlers for each page load event.
Just create a Stack / Queue for storing the pages you want to load:

```
Queue<string> pagesToLoad = new Queue<string>();

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pagesToLoad.Enqueue("http://www.test.com");
    pagesToLoad.Enqueue("http://www.test2.com");
    pagesToLoad.Enqueue("http://www.test3.com");

    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.first.com");
}
```

Then write your event handler method. When your browser finishes loading the page, it will call this method. You can run your code inside it and when you're ready, you can navigate to the next page.

```
webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: do whatever you want with the page you just loaded
    // You can get the page URL with e.Url

    // Get the next Url from the queue and navigate:
    if (pagesToLoad.Count == 0) 
    {
        return; // Finished!
    }
    else
    {
        string nextUrl = pagesToLoad.Dequeue();
        webBrowser1.Navigate(nextUrl);
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: This is a nice generic version of my answer. I only chose to go with the specific handlers to illustrate the workflow.